# USB Cables and AC Adaptors Multiple Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, usb, hardware, battery

In my office we have 11 different mobile devices that we use for testing our apps. We have Android Tablets, iPhone, iPads and some android phones.

Lately I can't seem to find an efficient charging procedure.

Some cables only charge (the devices) when plugged into USB (mac mostly), some cables only charge certain devices and some cables only connect with the computer but not charge.

We tried to buy new cables but it didn't work.

What would be a good strategy and setup for this kind of thing?

Comment: I must be missing something. Why aren't you using the charging blocks provided by the company, e.g. the 120V/220V Apple high current charging blocks for the iPhone and iPads, the standard high current charging blocks for the other devices?

Comment: They don't have anything like that. What should I suggest to my boss?

Comment: Just look on amazon or the like for "usb ipad charger" as well as for the other companies. The other companies should be standard USB, I imagine. Make sure you get one that will handle enough wattage otherwise it'll charge very slowly, e.g. ipad vs iPhone charging block.